# How to build bootable Linux image for running just a Golang simple app or simple web server?

Tags: go

Is it possible to use Golang script to do all the job? 
Preferably from windows. even using ready-made images for running Golang simple app will be good.
Similar to: [Tiny Linux OSes with Go](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/building-static-linuxes/) (This post not provided details)

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: my opinion is that you would be far better off using one of the "minimal" or "cloud" images from fedora for instance, or any other distribution you like, and add your requirements to that. Home-brewing your own distro is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a bootable consists of 3 steps:

```
Formatting the volume:

Copying a preconfigured iso to the volume:

Set boot flags on volume:
```

Unfortunately I am not fluent in goLang... You could do it all with your local shell and wrap that up in `syscall`s but that hardly feels like an answer.

Comment: There are a load of windows (cmd) examples under this search.

https://github.com/search?q=diskpart+cmd&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93